# Pip not working in secure corporate connection while ins

Tags: python, proxy, pip, anaconda

I am using a secure corporate connection. I am trying to install packages in python using anaconda command prompt. But I am getting an error saying

```
"Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError
(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x0000021AEDB01550>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. 
(connect timeout=15)')': /simple/sklearn/"
```

But when I tried it with my home wifi, there is no error.

I also tried using Conda Install. I got the following error

```
Fetching package metadata ...
CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url 
<https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your 
way.
ConnectTimeout(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-
64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError
(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 
0x00000219419AC5C0>, 'Connection to repo.continuum.io timed out. (connect 
timeout=9.15)'))",),)
```

I was researching stackoverflow for the problem and I found the following solution :

If you know your proxy information, you can pass that to your command line:

```
pip install --proxy=user:pass@server:port numpy
```

A full string could be something as simple as:

```
pip install --proxy=http://proxy.example.com numpy
```

Where `proxy.example.com` is your (corporate) proxy server. You only need to pass user:pass and port if the proxy also requires that information.

But the question is how to find the proxy name and port number for my PC. Also, how to insert that in the command because it is not clear for me.

Also, is there any other way I would overcome this problem?

Comment: You'd probably have to ask the people in charge of networking/IT in your organization to see if there's a proxy server you can connect through to reach pypi.